# Mongo driver updateMany not updating all documents

Tags: java, mongodb

Using Mongo Java Driver version 3.2.1 against MongoDB 3.0.12.

Calling `MongoCollection.updateMany(Bson filter, Bson update)` returns a result showing all expected documents were modified, however only a portion of the documents were actually updated.

I've tried with multiple write concerns: JOURNALED, ACKNOWLEDGED, etc

Any ideas?

Here is the profile result:

```
{ "op" : "update", "ns" : "dev.timeSheet", "query" : { "lineItems.task" : ObjectId("53233e85e4b07f573f1d4466") }, "updateobj" : { "$set" : { "lineItems.$.task" : ObjectId("53233e85e4b07f573f1d446d") } }, "nscanned" : 0, "nscannedObjects" : 6733, "nMatched" : 248, "nModified" : 248, "fastmod" : true, "keyUpdates" : 0, "writeConflicts" : 0, "numYield" : 52, "locks" : { "Global" : { "acquireCount" : { "r" : NumberLong(53), "w" : NumberLong(53) } }, "MMAPV1Journal" : { "acquireCount" : { "w" : NumberLong(301) } }, "Database" : { "acquireCount" : { "w" : NumberLong(53) } }, "Collection" : { "acquireCount" : { "W" : NumberLong(53) } } }, "millis" : 50, "execStats" : {  }, "ts" : ISODate("2016-08-25T18:17:16.025Z"), "client" : "127.0.0.1", "allUsers" : [ ], "user" : "" }
```

Update: Also occurs in MongoDB 3.2.9
Direct access calls:

```
db.timeSheet.find({'lineItems.task': ObjectId("53233e85e4b07f573f1d4466")}).count()
126
db.timeSheet.updateMany({'lineItems.task': ObjectId("53233e85e4b07f573f1d4466")}, {'$set': {'lineItems.$.task': ObjectId("53233e85e4b07f573f1d446d")}})
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 126, "modifiedCount" : 126 }
db.timeSheet.find({'lineItems.task': ObjectId("53233e85e4b07f573f1d4466")}).count()
90
```

Comment: Post the actual call to MongoDB and not a abstracted code. else no idea really

Comment: If by update you mean replace, then don't use the `$set` operator.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working the way I expected because it is only updating the first `lineItem` it finds for each time sheet.

[https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up.*S*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_)

> Remember that the positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the first match of the update query document.

No feature exists currently to update all items in the embedded array.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243